# How to hide variables from flask url routing?

Tags: flask

I'm making API and looking for a way to hide the extra information from the url. I have a function index:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    count = foo()
    return redirect(url_for("result", count=count))
```

and a function result

```
@app.route("/done/<count>")
def result(count):
    count = count
    return jsonify(count=count)
```

Inner function `count` allwase return different values. At the end I get a result like

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/done/43
```

But I need more common url view for universal API like

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/done
```

The problem is that if I remove `<count>` from endpoint, i get error

```
TypeError: result() missing 1 required positional argument: 'count'
```

Is there a way to override this?

Comment: Delete `count` variable from function definition `def result`.

Comment: Do you need to preserve `count` variable value?

Comment: If remove `count` from `def result` I get error. The count values  is needed to return at json file

Comment: I think that this is not possible then. Basically, you are redirecting to new url, with `count` variable as a part of it. `http://127.0.0.1:5000/done/count` request must be made in order to preserve that value between requests. If you still insists, you may store that value in cookie/session for each user or so.

Answer (score 2):

This task solving by session variable

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    count = foo()
    session['count'] = count
    return redirect(url_for("result"))

@app.route("/done/")
def result(count):
    count = session['count']
    return jsonify(count=count)
```